# what happen if docker base image and server OS is same

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to use docker for my new project. I implemented a project in my localhost and my OS in ubuntu and my project base image is CentOS, my server OS is CentOS too. 
now i don't know i should remove docker base image for deploying server and running or not?
when my base image and server OS is same, defining base image for server is extra and have overhead or not? it is necessary to be or it is extra?

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia:

```
Docker is a set of platforms as a service product that uses OS-level virtualization
to deliver software in packages called containers. Containers are isolated from one
another and bundle their own software, libraries, and configuration files; they can
communicate with each other through well-defined channels.
```

- What is the container?
  A container is a standard unit of software that packages up code and all its dependencies so the application runs quickly and reliably from one computing environment to another.
- What is the container image?
  A Docker container image is a lightweight, standalone, executable package of software that includes everything needed to run an application: code, runtime, system tools, system libraries, and settings.

Docker virtualizes your software from server OS, and your base image, CentOS, is software too.

1. now i don't know i should remove docker base image for deploying server and running or not? No, you shouldn't. these are two independent things and docker use your server os to run a container with CentOS base image.
2. it is necessary to be or it is extra? Yes, It is necessary. Docker base image is the basic image on which you add layers and create a final image containing your App.